# toggle vlc fullscreen using dbus and mpris

Tags: awesome, vlc, d-bus, multimedia

I am programming my keyboard shortcuts in awesome wm. At the moment I use qdbus to control media players and they all work except for full screen of vlc. The command I use is:

`qdbus org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Fullscreen`

This works to get the boolean value of the full screen status but should also be able to set it, what I already did is the above command followed with `true/false` (and a couple of variations on them) but it always gets interpreted as `false`.

`CanSetFullscreen` has value `true`

Comment: I have neither of _awm, qdbus_ or _vlc_ installed so just shooting in the dark... You could try with: `qdbus org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 Fullscreen true` assuming _CanSetFullscreen_ is _true._

Comment: @don_crissti you would think so, I tried true, True, TRUE, t, T, 1, boolean:true, ... all I could think of, and if the value was true to begin with it changes to false, so it does do something. I will change my question with this information.

Comment: If you introspect the object is there a property called _"CanSetFullscreen"_  ? If so, is it set to true or false ?

Comment: it is true while playing a video file and false in play-list modus, switching from full screen to windowed also works with the command, only setting it to full screen (true)  not, with other words no mater what I give for value it is always false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awesome has a way to send fake key events, this can be used to overwrite the standard keys used by vlc to match the keys configured in awesome wm. 
Inside ~/.config/awesome/rc.lua change the fullscreen key like this:

```
enter code hereawful.key({ modkey,           }, "f",      function (c) 
    if awful.rules.match(c, {class = 'Vlc'}) then
        root.fake_input('key_release','f')
        root.fake_input('key_press','f')
        root.fake_input('key_release','f')
    else
        c.fullscreen = not c.fullscreen  
    end
end),
```

to do this with other programs you first have to get to know the class of it, this you can get with the command `xprop | grep WM_CLASS`.

```
 WM_CLASS(STRING) = "vlc", "Vlc"
                     |      |
                     |      |--- class
                     |
                     |--- instance
```

Answer (score -1):

CanSetFullscreen is a read-only parameter, go check Fullscreen which is a read/write entry.
for D-Bus exploration, D-Feet on Ubuntu is quite good.

Comment: If you read the whole question you would see this is what I tried, I did not try to manipulate CanSetFullscreen